# Python For Loop using List - Trying to group number pairs based on last number used in loop

Tags: python

Starting with list:

```
l = [0,1,2,3,6,7,8,9]
```

Trying to produce:

```
nl [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9]]
```

Using a for loop, I was trying to iterate through the list, and use the previous number as my comparison to create a cluster group, with overlapping groups using numbers multiple times. It's not working, and I'm not sure why. It stops adding to the list once it gets to the 6.

*Edit: Yes, only grouping number sequence pairs, 1,2,3,etc. and skip 3,6

Test Code:

```
l = [0,1,2,3,6,7,8,9]
nl = []
lastN = 0

for i in range(1,len(l)):
    lastN = l[i - 1]

    if i - lastN == 1:
        nl.append([lastN, i])

    print('nl',nl)
```

This results in:

```
nl [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

My goal was:

```
nl [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9]]
```

Comment: Did you mean to exclude [3, 6] from the result?

Comment: @PaulBrown Yes, I'm pretty sure only number pairs that are in sequence should be printed

Comment: "It's not working, and I'm not sure why. It stops adding to the list once it gets to the 6." - because when i = 5, lastN = l[5-1]) which is element with index 4, which is 6. (List indices start at 0). Therefore "if statement": 5-6=-1, which is false.

Comment: @PaulBrown - Yes, [3,6] was meant to be excluded.
(lluxaKuk) - What had me confused is why it just stopped adding to the list when it reached the gap. I thought it would just skip it, and keep going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: 
https://repl.it/repls/SelfreliantNaturalDaemon

```
l = [0,1,2,3,6,7,8,9]
nl = []

for i in range(len(l)-1):
    if l[i+1] - l[i] == 1:
      nl.append([l[i], l[i+1]])

print('nl',nl)
```

Returns:

```
nl [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `l[i]` instead of `i` In your comparison and assignment, like this:

```
l = [0,1,2,3,6,7,8,9]
nl = []

for i in range(1, len(l)):
    lastN = l[i - 1]

    if l[i] - lastN == 1:
        nl.append([lastN, l[i]])

print('nl',nl)
# nl [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9]]
```

Your code partly worked before because `l[i]` is the same as `i` for the first few entries.

The code would be more readable and less prone to bugs if you used `l[i-1]` instead of `lastN` or assigned `nextN = l[i]` and then used that instead of `l[i]`. Or you can use the simpler list comprehension approach in [@Paul_Brown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57259178/3830997). But this identifies the specific error in your code.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. New to python here and using variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to do that:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
nl = []
for i1, i2 in zip(l, l[1:]):
    if i1 + 1 == i2:
        nl.append((i1, i2))
print(nl)
# [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

As a 1-liner list comprehension:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
nl = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(l, l[1:]) if b - a == 1]
```

Or expanded into a for loop

```
nl = []
for a, b in zip(l, l[1:]):
     if b - a == 1:
         nl.append([a, b])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
n1 = list(list(e) for e in zip(l[:-1], l[1:]))
```